# Should I use fixed positioning if I'm designing an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to design an iphone app and I'm planning on using PhoneGap.  I'm thinking about the menu bar I'm adding on the bottom of the window.  Should I fix the positioning or should I use absolute or relative or what?  THanks 0_0

Comment: It depends on your situation.

Comment: if you want bottom side then you can use bottom:0

Comment: Have you done some research already and care to share your findings or questions you have specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` This way the element will always be at the bottom of the screen, no mather on what device you view the webpage.

Comment: The Op was asking about an iPhone App. And there it works only if that device uses iOS 5.0 and up. And on iOS 5 `position:fixed` [is broken](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

**DONT FIX IT UP...**

Because if you fix it you would loose the best fit view between Iphone 5 and others.

Choose in way that it will be 10% from Bottom.

So this way you can have best fit for all the devices.